# Difference to group mean in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, mean, difference

Lets's assume I count how many oranges (`Orange`) and apples (`Apple`) people (`id`) eat in a certain time period. I also know if they are young or old (`group`). The pandas dataframe would maybe look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1','2','3','7'],
                'group': ['Young', 'Young', 'Old', 'Old'],
                'Apple': [7,2,5,4],
               'Orange': [3,6,4,4] })

  id  group  Apple  Orange
0  1  Young      7       3
1  2  Young      2       6
2  3    Old      5       4
3  7    Old      4       4
```

We can easily compute means using `groupby()`. E. g:

```
df.Apple.groupby(df.group).mean()
```

outputs

```
Old      4.5
Young    4.5
```

But let's say, I want to find how much the amount of apples and oranges consumed differs to the group mean per individual?

That is, the output should be

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1','2','3','7'],
                'group': ['Young', 'Young', 'Old', 'Old'],
                'Apple': [7,2,5,4],
               'Orange': [3,6,4,4],
     'Apple Difference': [2.5, -2.5, 0.5, -0.5] })

  id  group  Apple  Orange  Apple Difference
0  1  Young      7       3               2.5
1  2  Young      2       6              -2.5
2  3    Old      5       4               0.5
3  7    Old      4       4              -0.5
```

Is there a way to do this with pandas/numpy? Sorry for the rockie-question Best /R

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for `mean` with same `length` as `df` and substract by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
print (df.groupby('group')['Apple'].transform('mean'))
0    4.5
1    4.5
2    4.5
3    4.5
Name: Apple, dtype: float64

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['1','2','3','7'],
                   'group' : ['Young', 'Young', 'Old', 'Old'],
                       'Apple' : [7,2,5,4],
                       'Orange' : [3,6,4,4],
                       })
df['Apple Difference'] = df['Apple'].sub(df.groupby('group')['Apple'].transform('mean'))
print (df)
   Apple  Orange  group id  Apple Difference
0      7       3  Young  1               2.5
1      2       6  Young  2              -2.5
2      5       4    Old  3               0.5
3      4       4    Old  7              -0.5
```